# How should the various properties called "Homecoming" be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently three questions tagged with "Homecoming": https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homecoming . Two of those are about the 2018 TV series, and one of them is about a movie (and I'm not even sure which particular movie the poster is talking about).

The question about the (unknown) movie is currently on hold and will likely get deleted in the next couple of days, but that still leaves the question of how to tag the various properties with the same name in the future. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homecoming_(disambiguation) lists about a dozen movies with that title, for instance.

Should the current tag be changed to "homecoming-tv"? Or should it remain "homecoming" and any question about any of the movies with that same title should get a new tag consisting of "homecoming-" + the movie's year of release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given question is unclear about the movie it might be referring to. So, until it gets clear, we can keep it that way.

Regarding retagging the remaining two questions, there is no harm to keep the tag as is. It occurs very rarely that a question referring to a different Homecoming movie or TV series gets asked. If that happens, we can tag it with [homecoming-releaseyear](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homecoming-releaseyear).

Comment: IMO that would be the easiest things to do, especially with feature films.